# Replace an Array element in this.state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, crud

How do i replace an element(object) in *this.state.items* array with the content of *this.state.dataEdited*.
All of which is supposed to happen in the *handleEditUpdate* method

This.state

```
this.state = {
            name: '',
            day: '',
            dob: '',
            items : [],
            currentItem: {},
            dataEdited: {},
            toggle: false,
            loading: false
        }
```

I tried this in *handleEditUpdate* Method although its wrong and did not produce desired result but there was no major error(except that i mutated state directly)

```
handleEditUpdate(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const item = this.state.currentItem;
        let index = this.state.items.indexOf(item)
        if (~index){ 
          this.setState({
            items: this.state.items[index] = this.state.dataEdited
            });
        }
        this.setState({ toggle: false })
    }
```

handleEdit method

```
handleEdit(key){
        this.setState({
            currentItem: {...this.state.items[key]},
            toggle: true 
        });
    }
```

Render

```
        <form onSubmit={this.handleUpdate}>
                                <input 
                                    className=""
                                    name="name"                             
                                    onChange={this.dataChange}
                                    defaultValue={this.state.currentItem.name}
                                    placeholder= "Celebrant's Name" 
                                    ref={name => this.name = name}
                                    required /> 
                                <input 
                                    className=""
                                    type="number" 
                                    name="day"
                                    min="1" 
                                    max="31"
                                    ref={day => this.day = day}
                                    onChange={this.dataChange}
                                    defaultValue={this.state.currentItem.day}
                                    placeholder= "day"  />
                                <input 
                                    className=""
                                    name="dob"
                                    type="month"                                
                                    onChange={this.dataChange}
                                    defaultValue={this.state.currentItem.dob} />

                                <button type="submit">update</button>
                                <button onClick={this.handleEditCancel}>cancel</button>
                            </form>
                        )
                        :
                        this.state.items.map((item, key) => ( 
                        <li key={key}>
                            <span> {item.name} </span>
                            <span> {item.day} </span>
                            <span> {item.dob} </span>
                            <button 
                                className="btn btn-light"
                                onClick={() => this.handleEdit(key)} >edit</button>
                            <button 
                                className="btn btn-danger" 
                                onClick={() => this.handleDelete(key)}>delete</button>
                        </li>
```

Comment: what is this `if (~index){...`? you might mean `if (index>-1){...`

Comment: it means ```if(index !== -1)``` , it is some code i stumbled upon and I wanted to see its outcome

Comment: bitwise not operator, are you sure you wanted to use it like that? e.g. if index=1 then ~index is -2

Answer (score 2):

I think your trying to achieve this?
[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tbgn3f)

you need to split previous `state.items` before setting the new element, otherwise it will override by new item/s.

Adding

```js
handleEditUpdate(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const item = this.state.currentItem;
        let index = this.state.items.indexOf(item)
        if (~index){ 
          this.setState({
            items: [...this.state.items, this.state.dataEdited]
            });
           }
        }
        this.setState({ toggle: false })
    }
```

Replacing

```js
...
        if (~index){ 
          this.setState({
            items: [this.state.dataEdited]
            });
           }
        }
...
```

Removing

```js
...
        if (~index){ 
          this.setState({
            items: this.state.items.filter(i => i === ...)
            });
           }
        }
...
```

Comment: but *this.state.items* is an array ..does it apply?

Comment: sorry i missed that, updating answer

Comment: it is supposed to replace the specific item on display, it didn't..i just tried it out

Comment: So is a list with only one item?

Comment: no, multiple items but i tried running the update on one item but didn't get the desired result

Comment: do you have a unique id or field to search in order to find the item? I mean if item contains { id: 1,....} instead find item index... there is a better approach

Comment: i'll try to reproduce in a sandbox, WOI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210882/discussion-between-henrie-and-adolfo-onrubia).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using this code

```
handleUpdate(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        //const {name,day,dob} = this.state.dataEdited;
        const item = this.state.currentItem;
        let index = this.state.items.indexOf(item);
        const newItemList = [...this.state.items];
        newItemList.splice(index, 1, this.state.dataEdited);

        this.setState({ 
            items: [...newItemList],
            toggle: false 
        })

    }
```